# Get directory of file that instantiated a class ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have a gem that has code like this inside:

```
def read(file)
    @file = File.new file, "r"
end
```

Now the problem is, say you have a directory structure like so:

```
app/main.rb
app/templates/example.txt
```

and `main.rb` has the following code:

```
require 'mygem'

example = MyGem.read('templates/example.txt')
```

It comes up with `File Not Found: templates/example.txt`. It would work if `example.txt` was in the same directory as `main.rb` but not if it's in a directory. To solve this problem I've added an optional argument called `relative_to` in `read()`. This takes an absolute path so the above could would need to be:

```
require 'mygem'

example = MyGem.read('templates/example.txt', File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

That works fine, but I think it's a bit ugly. Is there anyway to make it so the class knows what file `read()` is being called in and works out the path based on that?

Comment: The directory of main.rb is irrelevant - it's the value of `Dir.pwd` that matters.

Comment: Ahh thanks that is what I needed. The problem was that `rspec` doesn't seem to run from the directory you would expect. So referencing the `templates` directory in `spec/` didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

There is an interesting library - [**i told you it was private**](https://github.com/fxn/i-told-you-it-was-private/blob/master/lib/i-told-you-it-was-private.rb). One can protect their methods with it from being called from outside. The code finds the caller method's file and removes it. The *offender* is found using this line:

```
offender = caller[0].split(':')[0]
```

I guess you can use it in your MyGem.read code:

```
def read( file )
  fpath = Pathname.new(file)
  if fpath.relative?
    offender = caller[0].split(':')[0]
    fpath = File.join( File.dirname( offender ), file )
  end
  @file = File.new( fpath, "r" )
end
```

This way you can use paths, relative to your Mygem caller and not pwd. Exactly the way you tried in your `app/main.rb`

Comment: Heh a very interesting gem :)

Comment: This does not always work. It breaks if the method is called indirectly, and if the method is called by another library. See my solution bellow.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use caller, and a lot more reliably than what the other people said too.

In your gem file, outside of any class or module, put this:

```
c = caller
req_file = nil
c.each do |s|
  if(s =~ /(require|require_relative)/)
    req_file = File.dirname(File.expand_path(s.split(':')[0])) #Does not work for filepaths with colons!
    break
  end
end
REQUIRING_FILE_PATH = req_file
```

This will work 90% of the time, *unless* the requiring script executed a Dir.chdir. The File.expand_path depends on that. I'm afraid that unless your requirer passes their `__FILE__`, there's nothing you can do if they change the working dir.

Answer (score 1):

Also you may check for [caller](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-caller):

```
def read(file)
  if /^(?<file>.+?):.*?/ =~ caller(1).first
    caller_dir, caller_file = Pathname.new(Regexp.last_match[:file]).split
    file_with_path = File.join caller_dir, file
    @file = File.new "#{file_with_path}", "r"
  end
end
```

I would not suggest you to do so (the code above will break being called indirectly, because of `caller(1)`, see reference to documentation on `caller`). Furthermore, the regex above should be tuned more accurately if the caller path is intended to contain colons.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for typical uses (I'm not sure how resistant it is to indirect use, as mentioned by [madusobwa above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14776155/2004045)):

```
def read_relative(file)
  @file = File.new File.join(File.dirname(caller.first), file)
end
```

On a side note, consider adding a block form of your method that closes the file after yielding.  In the current form you're forcing clients to wrap their use of your gem with an `ensure`.

Answer (score 1):

Accept a file path String as an argument.  Convert to a Pathname object. Check if the path is relative. If yes, then convert to absolute.

```
def read(file)
  fpath = Pathname.new(file)
  if fpath.relative?
    fpath = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),file))
  end
  @file = File.new(fpath,"r")
end
```

You can make this code more succinct (less verbose).